# PDO & PHP проверка значений

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Всем привет,такой вопрос,есть такая таблица в MYSQL

[image: Скрин]

В ней есть поля **slot** и **used**
Как мне сделать проверку по такой схеме:
Если у вещи **used = 1** то у любой другой вещи с таким же **slot** в PHP писало,что нужно убрать вещь с этого слота.

В данный момент код сам выглядит так:

```
$stmt = $go -> prepare('SELECT `weapons_users`.`id`, `weapons_users`.`id_weapon`, `weapons_users`.`used`,`weapons_users`.`onsell`, `weapons`.`name`, `weapons`.`slot` FROM `weapons_users` JOIN `weapons` ON (`weapons_users`.`id_weapon` = `weapons`.`id`) WHERE `weapons_users`.`id_user` = ? ORDER BY `weapons_users`.`dateAdd` DESC '.$pages -> get_limit());
    $stmt -> execute([$uid]);
    $get = $stmt -> fetchAll();

    $slot = [
      'boot' => ['name' => 'Ноги', 'damage' => 'Удар с ноги'],
      'hand' => ['name' => 'Тело', 'damage' => 'Удар с руки'],
      'head' => ['name' => 'Голова', 'damage' => 'Удар с головы'],
      'knife' => ['name' => 'Нож', 'damage' => 'Удар с ножа'],
      'pistol' => ['name' => 'Пистолет', 'damage' => 'Выстрел с пистолета'],
      'gun' => ['name' => 'Автомат', 'damage' => 'Выстрел с автомата']
    ];
    foreach ($get as $inv)
    {
      ?>
      <div class="fights fights-about">
        <table width="100%">
          <tr>
            <td width="58px" valign="top"><a href="info/items/<?php echo $inv['id_weapon'];?>"><img width="58px" src="/files/<?php echo $inv['slot'];?>/<?php echo $inv['id_weapon'];?>.png" title="<?php echo $inv['name'];?>" /></a></td>
            <td valign="top">
              <div class="attack-text"><a href="info/items/<?php echo $inv['id_weapon'];?>">
                <h1 class="human"><?php echo $inv['name'];?> <span class="small" style="color: #888;"><?php echo $slots[$inv['slot']]['ru']?></span></h1></a><hr/>
                <div class="quest-btn" style="margin: 5px 0"><?php
                if($inv['used']==1){
                echo'<a href="/inv/equip/'.$inv['id'].'">— Снять с себя</a>';
                }else{
                echo'<a href="/inv/equip/'.$inv['id'].'">— Надеть на себя</a>';
                }
                ?></div>
```

Comment: *Если у вещи used = 1 то у любой другой вещи с таким же slot в PHP писало,что нужно убрать вещь с этого слота.* Ну-ну... вот есть в слоте две вещи... и как же решить, какую из вещей в данном слоте предлагать убрать?

Comment: А по сути - при помещении шмота в слот надо другой шмот оттуда сперва выкинуть. Ну и констрейнт наложить, если версия сервера позволяет, дабы неповадно было надевать по десять штанов.

Comment: @Akina просто беда в том,что если например при уборке того что надето,я буду в базу писать used = 0, то не снимаются бонусы от шмотки у юзера.Вот беда в чем)По этому хочу заставить сначала снять старое,потом надеть новое
А получается как:
У меня есть инвентарь,в нем например два шлема,у обоих слот head, но у одного used = 1 а другого used = 0. Вот чтобы одеть тот у которого 0,нужно снять 1.Вот я и не понимаю как эту проверку сделать.По факту хотя бы через echo выводить текст надо,что необходимо снять старую вещь.
Ибо сейчас если я надену новую,не снимая старую,статы плюсуются.

Comment: *если например при уборке того что надето,я буду в базу писать used = 0, то не снимаются бонусы от шмотки у юзера.* Не понял... вообще-то при любой смене шмота все бонусы должны пересчитываться ЗАНОВО, С НУЛЯ. А не плюс то минус это...

Comment: @Akina, ну просто в двиге который мне достался статы считаются так
https://pastebin.com/BDg0cigW
Начинаются со 149 строки и далее идет подсчет атрибутов всех.
И как там исправить я не понимаю,по этому думал ограничить через кнопки снятия|надевания

Comment: Выкладывать бордюр граблями - занятие, несомненно, достойное. *как там исправить я не понимаю* Не понимаете как исправить - перепишите с нуля.

Comment: @Akina, p.s десять штанов никто к счастью надеть и не сможет.Ладно,спасибо,буду тогда пытаться вникнуть что-ж там написали)Ибо сам переписать не осилю)